# Java game - run code sequentially in the game loop

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist

I am creating a Java game within which the user can enter the commands of `up`, `left`, `right`, or `down` to move the character in that location for a certain amount of pixels. Within the `Player` class I am receiveing the commands from the user in an `ArrayList` of `JTextField`s after they have pressed the start button. I then use a `for` loop to go through all the inputs from the user and create `x` and `y` targets within a multi-dimensional array for the `x` and `y` amount of distance that the player needs to move. Finally I have a function called `updatePosition()` which is called within the main game loop. Within this function I loop through the multi-dimensional array of targets and have an `if` statement to check if the target has been reached or not. However when this method is executed and the user has input the commands of `up` and `right` for example, then the character moves diagonally up. I want a way which will move the character in the direction that the user has specified, executing them one after another.

Here is the code:

```
moveSpeed = 1;
private double moveAmt = 20;
private Double[][] targetCoordinates = null;
private ArrayList<JTextField> userInputTextFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
```

With method below I acquire the `ArrayList` of `JTextFields` within which the user has entered the commands and store it in a local `ArrayList`. I also instatiate an `Array` in the size of the amount of `JTextFields` that the user has entered the commands in. This array will be used to store the `x` and `y` targets for the character. I then lastly call the `moveChar();` method which will set the target `x` and `y`.

```
public void getInputText(ArrayList<JTextField> textFields){
    this.userInputTextFields = textFields;
    targetCoordinates = new Double[userInputTextFields.size()][2];
    moveChar();
}
```

This method will check if the commands that the user has enetered and set the `x` and `y` targets within the `targetCoordinates` array.

```
   private void moveChar(){

       for (int i = 0; i < userInputTextFields.size(); i++) {

            if(userInputTextFields.get(i).getText().equals("up")){
               targetCoordinates[i][0] = x;
               targetCoordinates[i][1] = y - moveAmt;

            } else if(userInputTextFields.get(i).getText().equals("down")){
                targetCoordinates[i][0] = x;
                targetCoordinates[i][1] = y + moveAmt;

            } else if(userInputTextFields.get(i).getText().equals("left")){
                targetCoordinates[i][0] = x - moveAmt;
                targetCoordinates[i][1] = y;


            } else if(userInputTextFields.get(i).getText().equals("right")){
                targetCoordinates[i][0] = x  + moveAmt;
                targetCoordinates[i][1] = y;
            }
       }
```

}

Finally, this is the method which gets called within the main game loop. It goes through the `targetCoordinates` array and checks if the targets have been met. If not then incriment or decrement the character's `x` and `y` position accordingly.

public void updatePosition(){

```
   if(targetCoordinates != null){

       for (int i = 0; i < targetCoordinates.length; i++) {

            if(y >= targetCoordinates[i][1]) {

                    moveCharacter(x, y - moveSpeed);

            } else if(y < targetCoordinates[i][1]) {

                 moveCharacter(x, y + moveSpeed);

            } else if(x > targetCoordinates[i][0]) {

                 moveCharacter(x - moveSpeed, y);

            } else if(x <= targetCoordinates[i][0]) {

                    moveCharacter(x + moveSpeed, y);
            }

       }

   }

}
```

Comment: And . . . what's the question? _"I want a way which will move the character. . ."_ doesn't tell us what you've tried or where you're stuck.

Comment: I think you want a "hopper" of commands that survive beyond a specific game loop and a new command is only fetched after the current one is completed. New commands go in the top and out the bottom to be excecuted

Comment: the question is : "I want a way which will move the character in the direction that the user has specified, executing them one after another."

Comment: @RichardTingle Can you give me an example of how I might be able to create that please.

Comment: @TedHopp I am stuck in the `updatePosition()` method which executes all of the commands which the user has specified all at once. I just want the character to move in the specified direction of the user one after another. I tried adding `breaks` within each of the `if statements` but then the loop did not move past the first directional command.

Comment: Assuming that `moveCharacter` correctly does what it's name suggests (you didn't show us that code), the code you posted for `updatePosition` looks like it should work. What is happening that should not happen? Or what is not happening that should?

Comment: @TedHopp The for loop seems to move towards all target locations within a single "tick"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present you use all the available commands to create a single target position and use that to direct your motion (or possibly move towards all target positions simultaneously).

Instead you want a "hopper" of commands that survive beyond a specific game loop and a new command is only fetched after the current one is completed. New commands go in the top and out the bottom to be excecuted.

This would most likely look something like this

```
public class Player {
    //holding commands as strings is a little bug prone, consider creating a custom class or enum
    ArrayList<String> commandsHopper=new  ArrayList<String>(); 

    //replace with some sort of Vector2i as improvement
    double[] targetCoOrdinates=new double[2]; 

    public void addCommand(String command){
        commandsHopper.add(command); //commands added at the top of arraylist
    }

    public void update(double timeSlice){
        //Called once, every game loop

        if (isAtTarget()){
            getNextTarget();
        }
        moveTowardsTarget(timeSlice);

    }

    public void getNextTarget(){
        if (commandsHopper.isEmpty()==false){
            //commands used from bottom of the arraylist
            targetCoOrdinates=determineTargetFromCommand(commandsHopper.get(0));
            commandsHopper.remove(0); //inefficient with arraylist, consider other collections
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read the question and trying to understand. I adapted your code to mine and it works.